# How to change the gas cost in ink! e2e tests

Tags: polkadot, ink, rust

I want to be able to adjust the gas cost used in specific ink! end-to-end (e2e) tests, but my attempts to do so have consistently resulted in a return value of zero when using the `weight_to_fee` function.